# permutations of only one position in a list while keeping the others fixed

Tags: python, permutation

I need help to create a function that is executed in multiple stages (0 to n)

> *For each stage (n), generate all possible assignments of number at position (n) in the list using each number positioned at index (n) and after (≥ n) in the list of numbers. The numbers positioned before index n (< n) remained unchanged.*

For example, at stage 0:

```
[1,2,3,4] will generate [[1,2,3,4], [2,1,3,4], [3,1,2,3], [4,1,2,3]]
```

at stage 1:

```
[1,2,3,4] should turn into [[1,2,3,4],[1,3,2,4],[1,4,2,3]]
```

at stage 2:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4] should turn into [[1,2,3,4], [1,2,4,3]]
```

and so on, so forth

I have tried:

```
import itertools
list(itertools.permutations([1, 2, 3, 4]))
```

but this returns ALL possible permutations

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: In your example, `[3,1,2,3]` is wrong, please fix it.

Comment: @smci yes you're right. it should be `[2,3,1,4]`. and I guess `[4,1,2,3]` is wrong too! it should be `[2,3,4,1]`. am I right?